# What does the hunting horn melody Sonic Waves do?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

Most of the hammer melodies I've come across thus far have been fairly self-explanatory, but I'm not really sure what the melody **Sonic Waves** does.

What does the hunting horn melody  **Sonic Waves** do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It acts like the Sonic Bomb: if there is a creature underground (like the Diablos), then it stuns him partially underground, allowing you to attack his head for a short period of time.